# $_Get Variable not able to store data in the database

Tags: php, sql

I am a newbie to php programming and was getting a error:

> Undefined index param and the data was not sent to the database

Please Help

```
<?php require_once("navig.php");
$cool=$_SESSION['user_id'];

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    ?>
<form name="form" method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"> 
<a href='http://www.amazon.in/?tag=rewardadda-21&param=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>'><img src=images/a.png ></a>
</form>

<?php
    require_once('connect.php');
    $dbb = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error communicating to MySQL server.');
        $cool=$_GET['param'];
    $querye = "INSERT INTO orderdata(user_id, store_used) ".
                        "VALUES ('$cool', 'amazon')";
    mysqli_query ($dbb, $querye);                       
    mysqli_close($dbb);     
}               
?>
```

Comment: You have no field in your form with id or name ` param`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't check is $cool=$_GET['param']; has any value ( is $_GET['param'] at $_GET array exists )

Try next :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  ?>
  <form name="form" method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
  <a href='http://www.amazon.in/?tag=rewardadda-21&param=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>'><img src=images/a.png ></a>
  </form>

<?php
  require_once('connect.php');
  $dbb = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error communicating to MySQL server.');
  if(isset($_GET['param'])){ // add this checking
    $cool=$_GET['param'];
    $querye = "INSERT INTO orderdata(user_id, store_used) ".
            "VALUES ('$cool', 'amazon')";
    mysqli_query ($dbb, $querye);                       
    mysqli_close($dbb); 
  }    
}
```

But it's bad practice -- create query from string in such way. Read about PDO and prepared statements

Also check that you pass GET param -- you should call your script like

```
/index.php?param=value1
```

Comment: Now the error is gone but no entry is veing made to the db,db name etc all are correct

Comment: did you pass GET param? Also check that you pass GET param -- you should call your script like

/index.php?param=value1

Comment: Basi cally sir wht i am trying to do is that the user id gets in the param variable and when the user clicks image it gets redirectef to amazon and entry is made with time in the db by extratcing user id from the url, that is this userid went at this time.Ok?Please help.Stuck